# ng-repeat in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Need to display a text area for displaying the details, once the details button is clicked.

It gives an output similar to this  [table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPRvE.png)

```
      <table>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <tr *ngFor = "let row of indexes">
        <td *ngFor = "let id of row>{{id}}</td>
        <td><button (click)="showDetails()">DETAILS</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

`<tr *ngIf="isClicked"><td>{{id.details}}</td></tr>` --->  This needs to be displayed very next to the row where the button is clicked.

In angular 1.x we can achieve this using ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end. In angular 2 I have an clue of including `</template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="indexes">`But not sure where to include this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to insert two table-rows for each of your `indexes`.

So if you have something like this in your component class:

```
rows: any[] = [
    { detailsVisible: false },
    { detailsVisible: false },
    { detailsVisible: false },
    { detailsVisible: false },
    { detailsVisible: false }
];

toggleDetails(row: any) {
    row.detailsVisible = !row.detailsVisible;
}
```

You can do it by using `ng-container`:

```
<table>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <tr>
            <td (click)="toggleDetails(row)">show details</td>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngIf="row.detailsVisible">
            <td>only visible after click on details cell</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>

</table>
```

Hope this helps.